# Is there a way to use an Accessor Function to define a property of an object in JS?

Tags: javascript, object, functional-programming

I have two inputs:

```
data = {"year": 2021}
valueAccessor = (d) => d["year"];
```

These two input can be dynamic, so I do not know what will be in the object or function.

**I want create a new object, and set values to that object using the Accessor function. Is there a way to do this?**

```
output = {}
output = definePropertyUsingFunction(output, valueAccessor, newValue)
```

Comment: No, There isn't...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "no". But...

If you're in some sort of controlled learning environment, there are some things you could try.

If you know for a fact that:

- Your `getter` function is pure (no side effects), and
- Your `getter` function always accesses 1 property,

you could

- Use a `Proxy` that tracks property access
- Make a call to the `getter` to trigger it (again, if this is a pure function it should not have any side effects)
- Write a value to the logged property

Here's a proof of concept:

```js
const data = { year: 2000, month: 1, day: 28 };

const getYear = obj => obj.year;
const getMonth = obj => obj.month;
const toString = obj => `${obj.year}/${obj.month}/${obj.day}`;

const writeViaSimpleGetter = (obj, value, getter) => {
  let propName = null;
  
  const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (target, key) => {
      if (propName) throw "Multiple properties accessed";
      propName = key;
    }
  });
  
  // Call the getter
  getter(proxy);
  
  if (!propName) throw "No property accessed";
  
  return { ...obj, [propName]: value };
}

// Simple getters work:
console.log(
  writeViaSimpleGetter(data, 2021, getYear)
)

console.log(
  writeViaSimpleGetter(data, 12, getMonth)
)

// This throws:
try {
  console.log(
    writeViaSimpleGetter(data, "oops", toString)
  )
} catch(e) { console.log("ERROR:", e) }

// This also throws:
try {
  console.log(
    writeViaSimpleGetter(data, "oops", () => {})
  )
} catch(e) { console.log("ERROR:", e) }
```